# How to get unique substrings in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 
                   'b':["west, east", "east, north","south, west","east, south"]})

   a            b                                                                                                                     
0  1   west, east                                                                                                                     
1  2  east, north                                                                                                                     
2  3  south, west                                                                                                                     
3  4  east, south
```

I want to get unique strings from column `b` like below.

**Expected Output:**

```
["east", "west", "north", "south"]   # order doesn't matter here
```

**My Efforts**

```
op = []
for _, value in df['b'].items():
    op.extend(value)

op = set(op)
```

Which is giving me correct result but is there more efficient way to do so?

My original dataset has around million rows and 1000s of unqiue values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create long string by `join`, then `split` and convert to `set`, last to `list`:

```
a = list(set(', '.join(df['b']).split(', ')))
print (a)
['south', 'north', 'west', 'east']
```

Or use `set comprehension` with `split` and flattening:

```
a = list(set([y for x in df['b'] for y in x.split(', ')]))
print (a)
['south', 'north', 'west', 'east']
```

Pure pandas solution is use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and convert to `list`:

```
a = df.b.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().unique().tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Just curious...  Is there a way to do the same with `pandas` methods?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - Yes, but is is obviously slowier, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to profile your code to determine if this is quicker for your particular usecase, but using pandas in-built vectorised methods might show some benefit on larger data sets.

Try using a combination of Series.str.split() and Series.unique().

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html

```
# Split column of lists into strings
df_split = df['b'].str.rsplit(',', n=-1, expand=True)

# For each column, get unique values and append to set
uniques = set()
for col in df_split:
    uniques.update(df_split[col].unique())
```